# PrintUnixDialog and mono

Tags: c#, unix, printing, mono

I'm new to Mono and I do not understand how the PrintUnixDialog and the PageSetupUnixDialog work

I have searched it on google for hours but I haven't found anything

So if you know a good tutorial please post the link, or if you have a working sample, that would be good too.

I hope my english is not too bad,
so Thanks in advance